# CSS Div Alignment and Positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a page that is similar to this:
http://bit.ly/1T8xGqP
Specifically, I'm talking about the row with the guy who is in the kitchen.

As I envisage it, this row consists of a text container and an image container encapsulated within a row container.

When the window is made smaller,the image appears to move behind the text column.

When the window is made larger, the text column sticks to the side of the image column. The image column sticks to the right side of the screen at all times.

I have been unable to create something like this.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="row_container">

    <div id="image_container">
    <img src="images/1297x756_image.jpg" width="1297px" height="756px" border="0" />
    </div>

    <div id="text_container">
    text
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#row_container {    
width: 100%
height: 756px;
background-color:black;
position:relative;
}

#image_container{
width: 1297px;
height: 756px;
background-color:#03C;
position:absolute;
right: 0;
}

#text_container {
width:  383px;
height: 756px;
background-color:blue;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
}
```

Can you please help me fix this? Thank you!!!

Comment: I cannot get the text container to stick to the left edge of the image container. I realize that this is because it is absolutely positioned left, but the current state of my code is the closest that I have been able to get to the desired outcome.

Comment: This did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should float the image and text and avoid using position:absolute.

CSS

```
#row_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 756px;
  background-color:black;
  float:right;
  background-color:#03C;
  position:relative;
}
#image_container{
  width: 912px;
  height: 756px;
  background-color:#03C;
  float:right;
  right: 0;
}
#text_container {
  width:   383px;
  height: 756px;
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
  left:0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="row_container">
<div id="image_container">
<img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/a601cb579cc9a289bc51cd41d8bcf478_large.jpg" width="100%" height="756px" border="0" />
</div>
<div id="text_container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sodales convallis bibendum. Donec ac elit id diam egestas ultricies. Curabitur porttitor nulla in odio porttitor congue. Ut eu magna justo. Etiam consectetur rutrum porttitor. Nullam tempus sodales volutpat. Sed interdum imperdiet tellus, id semper turpis facilisis vel. Curabitur sed ipsum nec nisl hendrerit viverra in ut felis.</p>
</div>
```

Do come back if you still face any issue.